# What is redirecting mobile visitors to our website?

Tags: htaccess

[Our site](http://www.louisbaxters.com.au/) may have been hacked.

It loads okay on desktop browsers, but on mobile devices it redirects to a porn site.

I can't see anything in the source code or .htaccess which would be causing this.

The site is Wordpress based, and it used to use Wordpress Mobile Edition, but that is now deleted, yet the symptom persists.

Can you see what is redirecting mobile visitors?

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, but have you contacted your hosting company? http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/626/20130312092853.png

Comment: Yes I have contacted our hosting company.  Waiting on a response.

Comment: Hmm. Unless the entire machine has been hacked, this is likely to be somewhere in the Wordpress code. It might be worth downloading the full source and searching it or the offending domain name; also if you have access to phpMyAdmin, I'd do a quick search for the domain in all tables. It's possible that the domain name is encoded in some form that renders this simplistic approach useless but it'd be a worthwhile first step.

Comment: Ask your web host to make your .htaccess Read Only. A writable htaccess is a very poor managed site to honest, all files that don't need constant updating should be read only. i.e if you don't do many template edits then ask them to make the template also read only. Most hax are header.php, and htaccess injections on wordpress. Do not under estimate the power of chmod ;)

Comment: Yeah they are read only already.  I've moved hosting providers.  About 6 of my websites got hacked with the last hosting provider - I'm not sure if it wasn't a hosting environment vulnerability instead of a website vulnerability.

Comment: I checked it on my phone and there is no problem now (12.24.2016)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a server side redirect.   There is something in the code that is powering your website that is detecting a mobile user agent and is issuing a 302 redirect.   Your site has been hacked.  I can confirm this with the following command line command.  I'm using a command line program called `curl` to download your website and setting the user agent to what an HTC Desire phone would use.

```
$ curl -s -D - -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; de-de; HTC Desire 1.19.161.5 Build/ERE27) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17' http://www.louisbaxters.com.au/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 09:34:27 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://crzyluxtds.in/go.php?sid=1
Content-Length: 217
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://crzyluxtds.in/go.php?sid=1">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is a thread from other people that have this problem: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/problems-viewing-site-on-mobile-iphone-htaccess-related

They suggest removing the following lines from all .htaccess files.  Even the .htaccess files hidden in directories:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://crzyluxtds.in/go.php?sid=1 [L,R=302]
```

You should also delete the following files that may have been added:

```
wp-includes/pomo
wp-includes/pm.php
```

**EDIT: Google launches new webmasters hacked page**

If you haven't already either yourself or your web design administrator can run your site using [Google's Webmaster Tools Hacked Page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/).

Comment: Something will be referring to them maybe in the SQL too. Since those standalone files must be called somehow, most likely in the header.php, made a edit to your question as Google just launched a new hacked website guide.

Comment: Good edit, bybe.

Comment: I had searched the .htaccess file, but it wasn't there.  When I searched all code in the site, http://crzyluxtds.in was found in .htaccess.  They'd put a hundred blank lines between their entry and the normal wordpress entry, making it hard to see on casual inspection.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Stephen, you saved me a big headache.